# Datatable works on my other page but not the other

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have a page where I need the table to be able to responsively shrink, and have the plus from DataTables to fit the screen for mobile. This feature works properly on one of my pages, but yet on the other It wont.

Checking the source code of the broken page, I can clearly see where DataTables is imported from the shared layout file.

Here is my script to get DataTables on the shared _Layout.cshtml

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.5/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

```
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.5/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.7/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
```

Can't figure out if its an import/ layout inheritance issue or just me structuring the table wrong.

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-priority="2">Status</th>
                    <th data-priority="4">Date Sent</th>
                    <th data-priority="1">From</th>
                    <th data-priority="3">Subject</th>
                    <th class="all" data-orderable="false" data-searchable="false">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var notification in Model.Notifications)
                {
                    <tr class="@(notification.IsRead ? "read" : "unread")">
                        <td><i class="fas fa-@(notification.IsRead ? "envelope-open" : "envelope")"></i></td>
                        <td>@notification.DateSent</td>
                        <td>@notification.From</td>
                        <td>@notification.Subject</td>
                        <td class="no-wrap">
                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="@nameof(NotificationController).AspName()" 
                            asp-action="@nameof(NotificationController.Details)" 
                            asp-route-id="@notification.Id" class="small button">View Message</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: And where is the javascript/jquery code that initializes the datatables?

Comment: It might be an issue with a part of the page you haven't shared.  The easiest and quickest way I know of to solve this issue is to create a third page that is a copy of the working page.  Then step by step, make one change at a time to make it more like the broken page, testing each time.  That should quickly find your issue.